# Is there a good(immutable) way to pre-define column for RDD, or remove column from RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to add columns to Spark RDD that I loaded from csv file and when I'm calling **withColumn()** it returns new RDD, I don't want to force new RDD creation, so can I somehow adjust RDD schema(best way I imagine is to add column in schema and then do a map by row and add value to new coulmn)? Same question goes if I can remove column from RDD somehow if schema is already defined by CSV file?

Comment: Actually it returns new `DataFrame` but could you explain what is wrong with that? It kind of looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/233847).

Comment: hey @zero323, I'm using csv files to convert them into rdds and join hem based on some column. But I have similar entities so I can't join them straight because I'll have exception that there are two colomns with sasme name. So I wanted to make alias for column or remove column that has same name when I don't need it to be joined

Comment: Maybe, I need an another coffee but it is still not that clear. Could you share a [mcve] which illustrates the problem?